# In npm how to pass env variable to another script command?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have 2 commands and another 2 commands that invoke the first two but with different env variables.

but setting env variable doesn't work.

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
"build:tests": "NODE_ENV=tests npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
"build:client": "webpack --config webpack.conf.js",
"build:server": "webpack --config webpack.conf.js",
```

but sadly, inside conf.prod.js i can't access node_env because it was written inside another script (1 "above" it).

Thanks